# Use values from one array as keys to find matches from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, `arrayOne` which I would like to use as keys to select values from other array, `arrayTwo`, and to display all found matches.

arrayOne:

```
Key: Value
0: 13
1: 17
2: 18
3: 19
4: 22
```

arrayTwo

```
Key: Value
13: value1
17: value2
18: value3
19: value4
22: value5
88: value6
99: value7
```

should give me the following output:

```
value1, value2, value3, value4, value5
```

I found many tutorials with comparing value by value or key by key, but how to compare values with matching keys?

Comment: please add your arrays. maybe we are talking about objects?

Comment: is arrayOne and arrayTwo object or array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having two arrays, you could map the first arrays indices with the values of the second.

```js
var one = [13, 17, 18, 19, 22],
    two = Object.assign([], { 13: 'value1', 17: 'value2', 18: 'value3', 19: 'value4', 22: 'value5', 88: 'value6', 99: 'value7' }),
    result = one.map(i => two[i]);

console.log(result);
console.log(one);
console.log(two);
```

Comment: so nice and thank you, result = one.map(i => two[i]); did the trick for me! Sometimes less is more :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about objects, you can use dynamic property notation with `map` and `Object.values` like so:

```js
const array1 = {
  0: 13,
  1: 17,
  2: 18,
  3: 19,
  4: 22
};
const array2 = {
  13: "value1",
  17: "value2",
  18: "value3",
  19: "value4",
  22: "value5",
  88: "value6",
  99: "value7"
};
const result = Object.values(array1).map(v => array2[v]);
console.log(result);
```

If you actually have arrays, however, you can just omit the `Object.values` and use `map` on `array1`:

```js
const array1 = [13, 17, 18, 19, 22];
let array2 = [];
array2[13] = "value1";
array2[17] = "value2";
array2[18] = "value3";
array2[19] = "value4";
array2[22] = "value5";
array2[88] = "value6";
array2[99] = "value7";
const result = array1.map(v => array2[v]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over it. Simple and fast enough for most scenarios.

```js
arrayOne=[13, 17, 18, 19, 22]
arrayTwo=[]
arrayTwo[13]="value1"
arrayTwo[17]="value2"
arrayTwo[18]="value3"
arrayTwo[19]="value4"
arrayTwo[22]="value5"
arrayTwo[88]="value6"
arrayTwo[99]="value7"

arrayOne.forEach((elem, index)=>{
  console.log(arrayTwo[elem])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly silly but quite compact way of getting the results would be

```
const matches = arr2.map(o1 => (arr1.find(o2 => o2.value === o1.key))).filter(obj => !!obj)
```

You map the values into a new array and filter out all `undefined` values.

Answer (score -1):

```
var result = []
arrayOne.forEach(function(val){
  arrayTwo[val] && result.push(arrayTwo[val])
})
```

Comment: Hey there! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.